# Why I see a blank page for the Keycloak's administration console?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, keycloak, quarkus

I'm using a Dockerfile for create a custom image of Keycloak as follows:

```
FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:18.0.2 as builder

ENV KC_HEALTH_ENABLED=true
ENV KC_METRICS_ENABLED=true
ENV KC_DB=postgres
# Install custom providers
RUN curl -sL https://github.com/aerogear/keycloak-metrics-spi/releases/download/2.5.3/keycloak-metrics-spi-2.5.3.jar -o /opt/keycloak/providers/keycloak-metrics-spi-2.5.3.jar
RUN /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh build

FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:18.0.2
COPY --from=builder /opt/keycloak/ /opt/keycloak/
WORKDIR /opt/keycloak
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh", "start"]
```

and whit this docker-compose I am able to run Keycloak:

```
version: "3.9"
services:

  keycloak_db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=$DB_USER
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=$DB_PASS
      - POSTGRES_DB=$DB_NAME
      - IGNORE_INIT_HOOK_LOCKFILE=true
    volumes:
      - ./db/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
    ports:
      - ${DB_EXTERNAL_PORT:-15432}:5432

  keycloak:
    container_name: keycloak
    # image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:18.0.1
    image: keycloak
    ports:
      - "${KEYCLOAK_EXTERNAL_PORT:-18180}:8080"
    environment:
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=${KEYCLOAK_USER}
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=${KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD}
      - KC_DB=postgres
      - KC_DB_URL_HOST=$DB_HOST
      - KC_DB_URL_PORT=5432
      - KC_DB_URL_DATABASE=$DB_NAME
      - KC_DB_SCHEMA=$KEYCLOAK_SCHEMA
      - KC_DB_USERNAME=$DB_USER
      - KC_DB_PASSWORD=$DB_PASS
      - KC_HTTP_ENABLED=true
      - KC_HOSTNAME=localhost
      - KC_HOSTNAME_ADMIN=localhost
      - KC_HOSTNAME_PORT=80
      - KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_BACKCHANNEL=true
      - KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS=false
      - KC_PROXY=edge
      - KC_PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true
      - KC_KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL=http://localhost:18180/
      - KC_KEYCLOAK_URL=http://localhost:18180/
      # - KC_LOG_LEVEL=debug
    depends_on:
      - keycloak_db
```

I can see the Keycloak homepage:
[image]

But when I try to go to the admnistration console I see a blank page:
[image]

---

What goes wrong?

---

**EDIT:**
I upgraded Keycloak version to 18.0.2.

And if I use KC_FEATURES=admin2 as further environment variable I can see something, but still not the admin console:

[image]

---

**EDIT 2:**
If I add `ENV KC_FEATURES=token-exchange` in Dockerfile for the builder, I can see the login page:

[image]

But after the log in... always a blank page:

[image]

Comment: Experiencing the same issue.. When I inspect the page and look at Network I see it tries to do a http call instead of https which we're using.. Hopefully someone knows what is going wrong here

Comment: Had similar issue with Keycloak admin ui and thanks to this and was able to determine the cause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `KC_HOSTNAME_PORT` is probably incorrect. If `KEYCLOAK_EXTERNAL_PORT` is set to 18180 and you are not behind a reverse proxy you should set `KC_HOSTNAME_PORT` to 18180.

This configuration is working:

```
 keycloak:
    container_name: keycloak
    # image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:18.0.1
    image: keycloak
    ports:
      - "${KEYCLOAK_EXTERNAL_PORT:-18180}:8080"
    environment:
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=${KEYCLOAK_USER}
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=${KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD}
      - KC_DB=postgres
      - KC_DB_URL_HOST=$DB_HOST
      - KC_DB_URL_PORT=5432
      - KC_DB_URL_DATABASE=$DB_NAME
      - KC_DB_SCHEMA=$KEYCLOAK_SCHEMA
      - KC_DB_USERNAME=$DB_USER
      - KC_DB_PASSWORD=$DB_PASS
      - KC_HTTP_ENABLED=true
      - KC_HOSTNAME=localhost
      - KC_HOSTNAME_ADMIN=localhost
      - KC_HOSTNAME_PORT=18080
      - KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_BACKCHANNEL=true
      - KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS=false
      - KC_PROXY=edge
      - KC_PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true
      - KC_KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL=http://localhost:18180/
      - KC_KEYCLOAK_URL=http://localhost:18180/
      # - KC_LOG_LEVEL=debug
    depends_on:
      - keycloak_db
```

Comment: confirmed was a misconfiguration. thanks

Comment: above variations of env variables doesn't fix the problem, still facing blank

Answer (score 0):

So we found that it was the `nginx` ingress controller causing a lot of issues. Moving to `haproxy` resolved this problem. As well, make sure you are interfacing with the ingress controller over `https` or that may cause issues with keycloak.

```
  annotations:
        kubernetes.io/ingress.class: haproxy
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Muhammed-sidhin/Keycloak

This is official Keycloak Docker image for development. It's based on Keycloak Official Docker Image, starting with keycloak-15

This configuration is working